# jQuery code not working on my local machine

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below code works fine on http://jsfiddle.net/saQTw/2/

for some reason it doesnt work on my local machine, i am not sure where i am making the mistake. Need an expert eye to look what i am doing wrong in this code.

Code which i got from the stackoverflow is support to populate the select list with dates
but i cant make it work on my local machine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script  type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script>
    function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
    var date = new Date();
    var selectElement = $('<select>'), optionElement;
    for (var count =0; count < 90; count++){
        formattedDate = pad(date.getUTCDate()) + '-' + pad(date.getUTCMonth()+1) + '-' +  date.getUTCFullYear();
        optionElement = $('<option>')
        optionElement.attr('value',formattedDate);
        optionElement.text(formattedDate);
        selectElement.append(optionElement);
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    $('#ddDate').append(selectElement);
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="ddDate"> </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried jQuery version 1.6 also it does not work

Solution for the above problem:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
    var date = new Date();
    var selectElement = $('<select>'), optionElement;
    for (var count =0; count < 90; count++){
        formattedDate = pad(date.getUTCDate()) + '-' + pad(date.getUTCMonth()+1) + '-' +  date.getUTCFullYear();
        optionElement = $('<option>')
        optionElement.attr('value',formattedDate);
        optionElement.text(formattedDate);
        selectElement.append(optionElement);
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    $('#ddDate').append(selectElement);
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle is not working either, some code is missing. Your `$('#ddDate')...` should be inside the function, and you should be calling the function somehow. You're also missing a ; on `optionElement = $('<option>')`

Comment: What is showing up?  Any error messages?

Comment: How exactly is it not working? What happens when click: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js ?

Comment: Your js console reports any error? have you got any 404 errors in firebug "net" panel?

Comment: Some posted the solution & deleted I was luck enough to read it on time. I tried to mark his answer as correct but i couldnt as it was deleted by the user, Anyways i appreciate his help. since i cant answer and dont want other to waste time on this so i will post soultion as part on question.

Comment: <script>
$(function(){
    function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
    var date = new Date();
    var selectElement = $('<select>'), optionElement;
    for (var count =0; count < 90; count++){
        formattedDate = pad(date.getUTCDate()) + '-' + pad(date.getUTCMonth()+1) + '-' +  date.getUTCFullYear();
        optionElement = $('<option>')
        optionElement.attr('value',formattedDate);
        optionElement.text(formattedDate);
        selectElement.append(optionElement);
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    $('#ddDate').append(selectElement);
});
    </script>

Comment: You should wrap your code within a ready event because right now it is executed before your markup even exists.

Comment: @StudentDubai: You can post that as an answer to your own question rather than include it in the comments

Comment: How are you invoking `pad(n)`? There is nothing in body like `onLoad` or in div like `onKeyDown`.

Comment: @StudentDubai. Don't post code in comments, it's unreadable. Edit your question or post the answer if you find it in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping the jquery in a [document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the #ddDate element before it exists. So either move the javascript part beneath the body OR wrap the code into `$(document).ready(function() {...})`

Answer (score 0):

In JSFiddle you are using the `onload` event to run `pad(n)`. You need to do the same here

Modify the `<body>` tag to `<body onload="pad(2)">`